# VS Code: Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, build

Here what I'm trying to do is build my flutter application using VS Code. When I'm run the following command `flutter build apk`

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'F:\year-03\SEM2\events\GSOC\LabelLab\labellab_mobile\android\build.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
        build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
        platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
     To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
     Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html   

     Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Mr.Semicolon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

To understand the exact solution I'll describe all the steps that I followed to setup Flutter in VS Code IDE.
1. Download Flutter Windows SDK from https://flutter.dev
2. Extract the file to the C drive
3. Go to the file path `C:\flutter\bin`and set the environment variable.
4. In VS Code IDE install the Flutter and Dart extensions.
5. Run the application using `flutter build apk`

Edit: 
`flutter doctor` output,

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.720], locale en-GB)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
[!] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.3)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.44.0)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Comment: Run `flutter doctor` and check the output

Comment: Check this document and follow the things mentioned https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to lack of license agreement.
Open your terminal.
`flutter doctor --android-licenses`
Press `y` to accept every license.

Comment: thaks for the answer but it gives an error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Comment: you have executed this command directly in vs code terminal, right? moreover kindly check is there mainActivity file available in the project or not.

Comment: checkout this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51670

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j/43574427#43574427 should be the case but still dont know how to resolve it

Comment: I would suggest to reinstall sdks to resolve your issue. Instead going to reinstall, You should try flutter clear, restart system, create new flutter project steps.

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake you got the answer buddy or still stuck in between?

Comment: I got the answer from above url but unable to solve my problem so I stop working on that

Answer (score 1):

In some machines, you need to open the command prompt as an administrator. So, you can try out the following steps and check

- Execute **command prompt as administrator**.
- Run the command `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and accept all.
  licenses by pressing **Y**.
- Run the command `flutter doctor -v` to check whether the issue is still there;
- Login as a regular user and try `flutter doctor -v` to make sure everything is okay.

If it still giving you the same issue visit your flutter folder and open the file called **flutter_console.bat** and type this command `flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14942

Check this issue as well it has a useful discussion about this issue.