# Error while building an flutter apk with vscode

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Hey I'm new flutter user i want to create an Android app with flutter using vs code without Android Studio is that possible ?

I have installed `android-sdk` and `openjdk-11-jdk` and
I'm getting some errors when i run `flutter build apk`

```
Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 30 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 30 not accepted.      
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     platforms;android-30 Android SDK Platform 30                       
     build-tools;29.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2                  
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
                                                                        
  Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk                               
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 1s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                    1,931ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

so some one help me to resolve this ?

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61250374/10084055

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and accept all